# How to filter an array of subdocuments by two fields in each subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to add a help request system which allows the requestor to make only one request for help on each topic from an expert.  If the expert lists multiple topics which they can help, I want to limit each requestor to one help request per topic per expert.

I am using node.js and mongoose.js with a self-hosted mongodb instance
I have tried using the `$and` operator to find the `._id` of the expert as long as they don't already have an existing request from the same requestor on the same topic.  It works for one update but after the experts document has a subdocument inserted with either the `topic_id` or the `requestor_id` the filter is applied and no expert is returned.

```
    // Schema
    ExpertSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      expert_id: String,
      helpRequests: [
       requestor_id: String,
       topic_id: String
    ]

    });

    //query
    const query = {
      $and:[
        {expert_id: req.body.expert_id},
        {'helpRequests.requestor_id': {$ne: req.body.requestor_id}},
        {'helpRequests.topic_id': {$ne: req.body.topic_id}}
      ]
    };
    // desired update
    const update = {
      $push: {
        helpRequests: {
          requestor_id: req.body.requestor_id,
          topic_id: req.body.topic_id
        }
    }
    Expert.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, {new: true}, (err, expert) =>{
    // handle return or error...
    });
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data.

Comment: your `helpRequests` array contains only `requestor_id: String,` and 
       `topic_id: String` not any other attributes right ?

Comment: @ShivamMishra That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting any expert is condition inside your query.

Results always returned based on the condition of your query if your condition inside query get satisfied you will get your result as simple as that.

#### Your query

```
{'helpRequests.requestor_id': {$ne: req.body.requestor_id}},
{'helpRequests.topic_id': {$ne: req.body.topic_id}}
```

you will get your `expert` **only** if `requestor_id` and `topic_id` is **not exists** inside `helpRequests` array. thats you are querying for.

#### Solution

As per you schema if `helpRequests` contains only `requestor_id` and `topic_id` then you can achieve what you desire by below query.

```
Expert.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
    expert_id: req.body.expert_id,
}, {
        $addToSet: {
            helpRequests: {
                requestor_id: req.body.requestor_id,
                topic_id: req.body.topic_id
            }
        }
    }, { returnNewDocument: true });
```